# does sifr 2 support r-t-l language fonts?

Tags: sifr

I want to work in sifr 2 with right to left language. But it seems that flash 8 doesnt support to unicode or r-t-l fonts.
Please help.....

Thanking in advance.

Answer (score 0):

sIFR (any version) doesn't support this.